javascript removing element style after clicking other
I'm trying to remove attribute "selected" from span element when other span element (not the same div) is clicked

and

How to remove attribute "selected" of span element in div_bottom1 while div1 another span is selected?


window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      const div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
      div1.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        const div1span = e.target.closest('span.swatch');
        if (!div1span) return;
        const dj = document.getElementById('div_bottom1');
        const djp = document.getElementById('div_bottom2');
        const dd = document.getElementById('div_bottom3');

        if (div1span.matches('.div1swatch')) {
          const clodj = dj.closest('span.selected');
          const clodd = dd.closest('span.selected');
          clodj.removeProperty('selected');
          clodd.removeProperty('selected');
        }
      });
<div id="attribute_pa_wersja-okleiny" class="tawcvs-swatches oss-" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_wersja-okleiny">
  <span class="swatch swatch-image swatch-dekor-jednobarwny selected" data-value="dekor-jednobarwny">
        <span class="swatch__tooltip"></span>
  <span class="swatches_image-container"><img src="standard.jpg" alt="dekory jednobarwne"></span>
  </span>
  <span class="swatch swatch-image swatch-dekor-jednobarwny-premium" data-value="dekor-jednobarwny-premium">
        <span class="swatch__tooltip"></span>
  <span class="swatches_image-container"><img src="premium.jpg" alt="dekory jednobarwne premium"></span>
  </span><span class="swatch swatch-image swatch-dekor-drewnopodobny" data-value="dekor-drewnopodobny">
        <span class="swatch__tooltip"></span>
  <span class="swatches_image-container"><img src="orzech-nicea.jpg" alt="dekory drewnopodobne"></span>
  </span>
</div>
<div id="attribute_pa_dekor-jednobarwny" class="tawcvs-swatches oss-" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_dekor-jednobarwny">
  <span class="swatch swatch-image swatch-bialy selected" data-value="bialy">
        <span class="swatch__tooltip"></span>
  <span class="swatches_image-container"><img src="bialy-150x150-2.jpg" alt="biały"></span>
  </span><span class="swatch swatch-image swatch-czarny" data-value="czarny">
        <span class="swatch__tooltip"></span>
  <span class="swatches_image-container"><img src="AR_16_9-150x150-1.webp" alt="czarny"></span>
  </span>
</div>
<div id="attribute_pa_dekor-jednobarwny-premium" class="tawcvs-swatches oss-" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_dekor-jednobarwny-premium">
  <span class="swatch swatch-image swatch-bialy-polysk" data-value="bialy-polysk">
        <span class="swatch__tooltip"></span>
  <span class="swatches_image-container"><img src="bialy-150x150-1.jpg" alt="biały połysk"></span>
  </span>
  <span class="swatch swatch-image swatch-burgundowy selected" data-value="burgundowy">
        <span class="swatch__tooltip"></span>
  <span class="swatches_image-container"><img src="burgundowy-150x150-1.webp" alt="burgundowy"></span>
  </span>
  <span class="swatch swatch-image swatch-czarny" data-value="czarny">
        <span class="swatch__tooltip"></span>
  <span class="swatches_image-container"><img src="czarny-polysk-150x150-1.webp" alt="czarny połysk"></span>
  </span>
  <span class="swatch swatch-image swatch-kaszmir-matowy" data-value="kaszmir-matowy">
        <span class="swatch__tooltip"></span>
  <span class="swatches_image-container"><img src="kaszmir-matowy-150x150-1.webp" alt="kaszmir matowy"></span>
  </span>
</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
   window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',() => {
      const div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
         div1.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            const div1span = e.target.closest('span.swatch');
            if (!div1span) return;
            const dj = document.getElementById('div_bottom1');
            const djp = document.getElementById('div_bottom2');
            const dd = document.getElementById('div_bottom3');
   
         if (div1span.matches('.div1swatch')) {
            const clodj = dj.closest('span.selected');
            const clodd = dd.closest('span.selected');
            clodj.removeProperty('selected');
            clodd.removeProperty('selected');
         }
   });
</script>

It works till getting div1span.matches('.div1swatch') and then:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null" error

div 2-4 are separate divs outside div1 and have style.display = "none"; set while div1span is switched
Clicking on div1span sets style.display = "none"; to div_bottom2 and div_bottom3.
Clicking on div2span sets style.display = "none"; to div_bottom1 and div_bottom3
Clicking on div3span sets style.display = "none"; to div_bottom1 and div_bottom2
Is it related?
What I'm doing wrong? I'm javascript newbie, coding in php + html so far
html
javascript

"span.selected" matches <span> elements with the class "selected", not an attribute called "selected". If those selectors work, then you want clodj.classList.remove("selected").

Still not working, Stuck with Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList'). Is is related with setting style.display = "none"; to div which is not active?

Settings styles makes no difference on the selectability of an element in JS (unless you specifically check for certain styles). Could you also add some example HTML here and hook it up into a snippet so we can see what's happening? This should be simple enough to create a minimal, reproducible sample.

I would have done a click event like this: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onclick your click event only works on one specific div,. Can you make an example here so we can look at it: https://jsfiddle.net/

@MoDGenesis I would have used .addEventListener but that's neither here nor there.

@Aquarius that means dj.closest('span.selected') is returning null, meaning there is no parent <span> with class "selected". Also without seeing your HTML it's really hard to tell what's going on, but putting <div> elements inside <span> elements is poor markup style.

Your question is hard to understand. The images you posted make it even harder. Why don't you assign a click to all your .swatch boxes? Why not use a variable to store the currently selected one?

Alright, I took the code and pastebin it:
html
javascript

Why not create a jsfiddle.net ? Also you still need to explain what you're actually after, what is that you're creating and how should it all work. To me currently it all seems like you didn't need any JS at all. You could have used CSS and radio buttons. Also - What should happen if one clicks and already selected item?

You need to loop through the boxes that are selectable  and remove the style attribute unless its the current target. How else do you expect this to work if you don‘t remove the selected class from an old element when you click on a new one

I made a snippet of the code you had posted and formatted it a bit - it is clearly broken as illustrated when you run it.

@Aquarius ... Regarding the so far provided answers / solutions, are there any questions left?

Sorry, we had long holidays in Poland, I'll check the solutions today

<script>
      document.getElementById("swatches")
     .addEventListener("click",function(ev) {
        var element = ev.target.closest(".swatch");
        var selectedSwatches = document.querySelectorAll(".selected");
        selectedSwatches.forEach(function (swatch) {
          swatch.classList.remove("selected");
        });
        if (element) {
          element.classList.toggle("selected");
        }
      });
    </script>

<!-- language: lang-css -->

    <style>
    .row {
      display: flex;
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
      gap: 1rem;
    }

    .swatch {
      display: inline-flex;
      width: 3rem;
      background:red;
      aspect-ratio: 1;
      cursor: pointer;
      &.selected {
        border-color: #0bf;
        &::after {
          margin: auto;
          content: "✓";
        }
      }
    }

    </style>



<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <h2>JavaScript addEventListener()</h2>

    <p>This example uses the addEventListener() method to attach a click event to a button.</p>

    <button id="myBtn">Try it</button>
          <div id="swatches">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="swatch"></div>
        <div class="swatch"></div>
        <div class="swatch"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="swatch"></div>
        <div class="swatch"></div>
        <div class="swatch"></div>
        <div class="swatch"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>


Yes, almost, but...  swatches is ID of div at the top and clicking on span elements in that div should deselect only elements at the bottom divs which have different div ids like "bottom div1", "bottom div2" and "bottom div 3". Right now it also deselect span in top div

Ofcourse I can use document.querySelectorAll("#div_bottom1 .selected, #div_bottom2 .selected, #div_bottom3 .selected"); but it still removes .selected class in top div spans

Removing if (element) { element.classList.toggle("selected"); } did the trick

The entire functionality can be achieved without any JavaScript but with just pure HTML/CSS. It only requires some markup changes and applying some fitting css rules.
The usage of the <label/> / <input type="radio"/> relationship together with the functional :has() CSS pseudo-class as well as the usage of the content CSS property together with the attr CSS function mainly does the trick.
And falling back to form-controls enables keyboard navigation as well.


.item-overview {
  .row {
    display: flex;
    gap: .25rem;
    margin-bottom: .25rem;
  }
  label {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-flex;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    width: 4rem;
    border: 2px solid #a4a4a4;
    cursor: pointer;

    &:focus-within {
      border-style: dashed;
      border-color: red!important;
    }
    &::before {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      content: attr(data-name);
      background-color: #e0feff;
      align-content: center;
      text-align: center;
    }/*
    &::after {
      background-color: red;
    }*/
    &:has(:checked) {
      border-color: #0bf;

      &::after {
        position: absolute;
        top: 3px;
        width: 100%;
        content: "✓";
        text-align: center;
      }
    }
    > [type="radio"] {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: -1;
    }
  }
}
#rolex {
  label {
    border-color: #ccc; 

    &::before {
      background-color: #ffccf1;
    }
    &:has(:checked) {
      border-color: #f0b;
    }
}
<div id="swatch" class="item-overview">
  <div class="row">

    <label data-name="Swatch 1">
      <input type="radio" name="swatch" value="swatch-1" />
    </label>
    <label data-name="Swatch 2">
      <input type="radio" name="swatch" value="swatch-2" />
    </label>
    <label data-name="Swatch 3">
      <input type="radio" name="swatch" value="swatch-3" />
    </label>
    <label data-name="Swatch 4">
      <input type="radio" name="swatch" value="swatch-4" />
    </label>

  </div>
  <div class="row">

    <label data-name="Swatch 5">
      <input type="radio" name="swatch" value="swatch-5" />
    </label>
    <label data-name="Swatch 6">
      <input type="radio" name="swatch" value="swatch-6" />
    </label>
    <label data-name="Swatch 7">
      <input type="radio" name="swatch" value="swatch-7" />
    </label>
    <label data-name="Swatch 8">
      <input type="radio" name="swatch" value="swatch-8" />
    </label>

  </div>
</div>

<div id="rolex" class="item-overview">
  <div class="row">

    <label data-name="Rolex 1">
      <input type="radio" name="rolex" value="rolex-1" />
    </label>
    <label data-name="Rolex 2">
      <input type="radio" name="rolex" value="rolex-2" />
    </label>
    <label data-name="Rolex 3">
      <input type="radio" name="rolex" value="rolex-3" />
    </label>

  </div>
  <div class="row">

    <label data-name="Rolex 4">
      <input type="radio" name="rolex" value="rolex-4" />
    </label>
    <label data-name="Rolex 5">
      <input type="radio" name="rolex" value="rolex-5" />
    </label>
    <label data-name="Rolex 6">
      <input type="radio" name="rolex" value="rolex-6" />
    </label>

  </div>
</div>



Edit ... regarding Roko C. Buljan's comment ...

Yes, as said in comments, RADIO buttons is indeed a viable solutions - it depends only if one needs the ability to at some point deselect all the items - which in this specific case is not possible ... – Roko C. Buljan

Deselecting the currently checked radio-control within a radio-group is a very easy task. The necessary snippet would just augment the already working JavaScript-free solution.
The approach is as follows.
One does combine event-delegation, a WeakMap for looking up the radio-group's last (selected) value and the possibility of selecting a radio-control's correct/related radio-group/RadioNodeList via the named items of the control's related HTMLFormControlsCollection like e.g. with ... target.form.elements[target.name] ... which by the way equals the usage of something referred to as "DOM Level 0" API, an unfortunately far too seldom used technique despite having proven itself for more than 25 years.


function enableOverviewItemUncheckBehavior() {
  const lastRadioGroupValues = new WeakMap;

  function handleUncheckControl({ target }) {
    target = target.closest('[type="radio"]');

    if (target) {
      const nodeList = target.form.elements[target.name];

      if (
        lastRadioGroupValues.get(nodeList) !== nodeList.value
      ) {
        lastRadioGroupValues.set(nodeList, nodeList.value);
      } else {
        target.checked = false;
      }
    }
  }
  document
    .querySelectorAll('form:has(.item-overview)')
    .forEach(elm => {
      elm.addEventListener('click', handleUncheckControl)
    });
}

enableOverviewItemUncheckBehavior();
fieldset {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}
.item-overview {
  .row {
    display: flex;
    gap: .25rem;
    margin-bottom: .25rem;
  }
  label {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-flex;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    width: 4rem;
    border: 2px solid #a4a4a4;
    cursor: pointer;

    &:focus-within {
      border-style: dashed;
      border-color: red!important;
    }
    &::before {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      content: attr(data-name);
      background-color: #e0feff;
      align-content: center;
      text-align: center;
    }/*
    &::after {
      background-color: red;
    }*/
    &:has(:checked) {
      border-color: #0bf;

      &::after {
        position: absolute;
        top: 3px;
        width: 100%;
        content: "✓";
        text-align: center;
      }
    }
    > [type="radio"] {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: -1;
    }
  }
}
#rolex {
  label {
    border-color: #ccc; 

    &::before {
      background-color: #ffccf1;
    }
    &:has(:checked) {
      border-color: #f0b;
    }
}
<form>
  <fieldset id="swatch" class="item-overview">
    <div class="row">

      <label data-name="Swatch 1">
        <input type="radio" name="swatch" value="swatch-1" />
      </label>
      <label data-name="Swatch 2">
        <input type="radio" name="swatch" value="swatch-2" />
      </label>
      <label data-name="Swatch 3">
        <input type="radio" name="swatch" value="swatch-3" />
      </label>
      <label data-name="Swatch 4">
        <input type="radio" name="swatch" value="swatch-4" />
      </label>

    </div>
    <div class="row">

      <label data-name="Swatch 5">
        <input type="radio" name="swatch" value="swatch-5" />
      </label>
      <label data-name="Swatch 6">
        <input type="radio" name="swatch" value="swatch-6" />
      </label>
      <label data-name="Swatch 7">
        <input type="radio" name="swatch" value="swatch-7" />
      </label>
      <label data-name="Swatch 8">
        <input type="radio" name="swatch" value="swatch-8" />
      </label>

    </div>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset id="rolex" class="item-overview">
    <div class="row">

      <label data-name="Rolex 1">
        <input type="radio" name="rolex" value="rolex-1" />
      </label>
      <label data-name="Rolex 2">
        <input type="radio" name="rolex" value="rolex-2" />
      </label>
      <label data-name="Rolex 3">
        <input type="radio" name="rolex" value="rolex-3" />
      </label>

    </div>
    <div class="row">

      <label data-name="Rolex 4">
        <input type="radio" name="rolex" value="rolex-4" />
      </label>
      <label data-name="Rolex 5">
        <input type="radio" name="rolex" value="rolex-5" />
      </label>
      <label data-name="Rolex 6">
        <input type="radio" name="rolex" value="rolex-6" />
      </label>

    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>




Yes, as said in comments, RADIO buttons is indeed a viable solutions - it depends only if one needs the ability to at some point deselect all the items - which in this specific case is not possible. But glad you shared this one as well.

@RokoC.Buljan ... I did provide a 2nd approach which on top of the JS-free solution applies the ability of unchecking checked radio controls within a radio-node-list / radio-group.

This one works great but this is not what I meant for. Top and bottom group of span elements are separated. Clicking each one of them shows div with spans below. And then - If I click other span element at the top it shows different div with span elements below - AND which more important - deselect previuos selected span in other divs at below

@Aquarius ... targeting ... "Top and bottom group of span elements are separated." ... Regarding the behavior of an UI and its elements; how accessible/operable (user) and maintainable (development) they are depends to a much bigger part on thoughtfully crafted markup than a lot of developers are aware of. A meaningful html structure can save tons of scripting, especially if it comes to form-control like elements/components. Thus the OP should be open to changing the span based markup hell (empty span-elements are always a sign of poorly chosen markup) to something better.

Store in a variable let elBoxSelected; the selected item (Element)
Assign a click to all(!) your boxes (not only to the ones in #div1)


let elSwatchSelected;

document.querySelector("#swatches").addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
  const elSwatch = ev.target.closest(".swatch");

  if (!elSwatch) return; // Not a swatch box. Do nothing.

  if (elSwatch !== elSwatchSelected) {
    elSwatchSelected?.classList.remove("selected"); // Deselect previous (if any)
    elSwatchSelected = elSwatch; // Make this one the new seelected
  }

  elSwatchSelected.classList.toggle("selected"); // Toggle 

});
.row {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.swatch {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  width: 3rem;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  &.selected {
    border-color: #0bf;
    &::after {
      margin: auto;
      content: "✓";
    }
  }
}
<div id="swatches">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="swatch"></div>
    <div class="swatch"></div>
    <div class="swatch"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="swatch"></div>
    <div class="swatch"></div>
    <div class="swatch"></div>
    <div class="swatch"></div>
  </div>
</div>




This one works great but this is not what I meant for. Top and bottom group of span elements are separated. Clicking each one of them shows div with spans below. And then - If I click other span element at the top it shows different div with span elements below - AND which more important - deselect previuos selected span in other divs at below
